# From "client tdp session number" to "session number"

Tags: teradata

My question is related to the Teradata DB with Unity.

My starting point is the Client TDP Session Number from the connection.

My target is to obtain the Session Number (the same that you can obtain with the command SELECT SESSION) or the Unity Session Number.

Is there any system tables or views that I can use to extract this information?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with "select session;"?

Comment: I am in a different session, so "select session" will provide my Session Number, not the one I have to check for the users.

Suppose I am logged in the SessionA. I need to set session information for a logged user in SessionB. 

I hope this help to understand my answer.

Comment: There's *dbc.SessionInfoV*, *SESSION LIST* in unityadmin, and *SYSLIB.MonitorSession*, don't know if they're what you want.

Comment: Is UnitySessNo populated in dbc.SessionInfoV / dbc.LogOnOffV with your software releases?

Comment: Yes,  dbc.SessionInfoV / dbc.LogOnOffV are populated.

Comment: If present, the UnitySessNo should be the session number between the client and Unity. SessionNo is the session number between Unity and the database.

Comment: Thanks, Fred, for your information. I wonder if a table or a view exists where the association between Client TDP Session Number and Unity Session Number is saved.  Knowing this would solve my problem.